# How to use a LEFT function within xlExpression in FormatConditions.Add method?

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting, listobject

I want to set up a conditional formatting within a range base on a LEFT(cell,1) value. Within this range a have a value "1A" and I want to paint it red if the first character LEFT() equals 1. My code does nothing. How can I achieve that?

My code

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting()

  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, condition2 As FormatCondition
  
  Dim tbl As ListObject
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Overview").ListObjects("Column_Overview")
  
  Dim tblLastColumn As Integer
  tblLastColumn = tbl.Range.Columns.Count
  

 'Fixing/Setting the range on which conditional formatting is to be desired
  Dim rng As Range
  Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Resize(, tblLastColumn - 7)
  
  'Defining and setting the criteria for each conditional format
 
   Set condition1 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(Left(xlCellValue, 1), xlEqual, "=1")
   Set condition2 = rng.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, "=50")

   'Defining and setting the format to be applied for each condition
   With condition1
    .Font.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Bold = True
   End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub testFormatCondLeft()
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition
  Dim condition1 As FormatCondition, rng As Range
  
  'your existing code...
  Set rng = tbl.ListColumns(8).DataBodyRange.Resize(, tblLastColumn - 7)
  With rng
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    Set condition1 = .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=Left(" & .cells(1).Address(0, 0) & ", 1)=""1""")
  End With
   With condition1
    .Font.Color = vbRed
    .Font.Bold = True
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @timetravelprimer: Didn't you find some time to test the above suggestion? If tested, is there any problem with it?

Comment: Invalid procedure call error. I've tried to put an explicit cell referece but same issue:

Dim condition1 As FormatCondition

rngX.FormatConditions.Delete

Set condition1 = rngX.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, _
Formula1:="=LEFT(H2,1)=1")

Comment: This works but not what I'm trying to achieve: Set condition1 = Selection.FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=H2=""1A""")

Comment: Needed to change the formula into IF statement. Formula1:="=IF(LEFT(H2,1)=""1A"",TRUE,FALSE)" and it worked!

Comment: @timetravelprimer: The Left parameter to be cheked MUST BE A STRING! The formula like you can see it in Excel should use `=LEFT(H2,1)="1")` and this is written from VBA like `=LEFT(H2,1)=""1"""`. So it is in my code, which has been tested...

Comment: @timetravelprimer:  So, did my code answer your question? If yes, we here vote it up if necessary notoriety and even more important, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works...